# Effect on mAh of connecting 2 batteries in series

Tags: batteries

Two batteries, each at 1000 mAh let's say, connecting them in series will not result in a 2000mAh capacity, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

Let's say they're 12 V batteries.

**Parallel connection**

12 V x 2000 mAh = 12 V x 2 Ah = 24 Wh.

**Series connection**

24 V x 1000 mAh = 24 V x 1 Ah = 24 Wh.

The total energy is always the same as it is just the sum of the battery energies.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting two 1000mAh batteries in series and using them as a single battery still makes it a 1000mAh battery, but with double the voltage.

Batteries are often connected in series, but when doing so it is best that all batteries are of the same kind (brand, ...) and have the same charge when putting them in series to limit the risk of (dis)charging one (much) more than the other.